# QregExp class PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qregexp

I am trying to achieve the following, however with the QRegExp class in PyQt4.

I am struggling to find good examples on how to use this class in python.

```
def html_trap(text):
    h ={"&":"&amp;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&apos;",">":"&gt;","<":"&lt;"}
    t=""
    for key,value in h.items():
        m=re.search(value,text)
        if m is not None:
            t=text.replace(value,key)
    return t

print(html_trap("Grocery &quot; Gourmet Food"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of search you must use `search()` you must use `indexIn()`, this returns the position of the found element or -1 if you can not find it

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore


def html_trap(text):
    h ={"&": "&amp;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&apos;",">":"&gt;","<":"&lt;"}
    t=""
    for key, value in h.items():
        regex = QtCore.QRegExp(value)
        if regex.indexIn(text) != -1:
            t = text.replace(value, key)
    return t

print(html_trap("Grocery &quot; Gourmet Food"))
```

Output:

```
Grocery " Gourmet Food
```